# the best way to copy new records from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql

whose structures are identical and which even have the same id's, now one of these databases collects information from a live feed, what i want to do is find a way to add just the new records to the second database so that the information can then be reviewed and managed, without disturbing the first database.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you use mysql replication?

Comment: What is the scope of this project?  Replication will work nicely for you, but might be overkill depending on what you need to do.

Comment: we are collecting ip addresses of visitors, looking up the data on ripe and identifying companies.  I have copied the database so we can update the information without effecting the main database, but i want to move the new data in every day to the second database.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your tables and whether or not you want to be selective about what you move from table1 to table2:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (field1,field2,field3)
SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table1
```

Should to the trick, add orders and where clauses etc as required!

Comment: how would identify just new data that exists in table 1 and not table 2 and insert that, thats the part i am having trouble with.

Comment: Assuming that one of your fields is defined as a primary key, you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` This will insert rows that don't exist, and ignore rows that do. If you do it without IGNORE, rows that already exist in the second database will cause the operation to die with a duplicate key error.

Comment: There are many other ways, you could update a flag in your master table and only insert those records that aren't flagged.  If its a once a day thing, you could do it on date, if you have a date field - by only selecting records from the previous day.