# PHP Mysql copy a record into a different database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two separate remote databases, the table in both databases is identicle and I want to copy a record from the old database to the new using PHP

While this [the best way to copy new records from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932232/the-best-way-to-copy-new-records-from-one-database-to-another) gives the solution as

```
mysqli_query($db1,"SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table1");

mysqli_query($db2,"INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3)");
```

Because of the number of fields involved I want to try and avoid naming all the fields

I was thinking of something like this...

```
$m = mysqli_query($db1,"SELECT * FROM table1");
```

****THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK****

HOW DO I GET TO THIS FROM THE ABOVE STATEMENT?

```
$values = "'".implode("','",array_values($m))."'"; 
$columns = implode(",",array_keys($m));
```

So I can do this

```
mysqli_query($db2,"insert into table1 ($columns) values ($values)")
```

I'm aware I will need to change the PRIMARY KEY id to null.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you sure you need `PHP`? `mysqldump -h host1 db1 mytable | mysql -h host2 db2` would do just fine

Comment: how do i do a foreach to get the columns and values from the mysql?

Comment: I need to use PHP because it's a web function? it allows a user to migrate an old record to the new database

Comment: Sorry I've updated the code to be clearer

Comment: @JimSMith - you could use exec() for calling external program mysqldump, but I think that would lead to a security issue instead.

Comment: i don't understand the host1 and host2, wouldn't these need to be defined in the exec?

Comment: @JimSMith - if using the exec approach I guess you would have to create a string with something like exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > --user2=... --password2=... --host2=... DB_NAME2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch the actual column names you could do like this:

```
$sql="SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_name = table1";
```

Fetch the above into an array.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$cols = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

and create comma-separated list into $columns-variable

```
$columns = implode(",", $cols);
```

For the values, just do a regular select-statement:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$vals = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 2):

in the end it was quite simple to modify my own code and create the array using mysqli_fetch_assoc

```
$m = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db1,"SELECT * FROM table1"));
```

and then to make the id null

```
$m["id"] = 'replacethis';
$values = str_replace("'replacethis'","null","'".implode("','",array_values($m))."'"); 

$columns = implode(",",array_keys($m));
```

then finally...

```
mysqli_query($db2,"insert into table1 ($columns) values ($values)");
```