# Mysqli db to db copy and strange charset behaviour

Tags: php, mysqli, copy

I converted a lot to mysqli so far but cannot get it to work.

What I want is to copy row with 50+ columns from DB1 to DB2 but don't know how or where to reference FROM DB1

```
    $query="INSERT INTO `action_templates`(`field1` `...`)
SELECT `field1`, `...` 
FROM `action_templates` WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
mysqli_query($DB2, $query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
```

As alternative I tried the following but 1) php side it obviously dont escape the  utf8 (& # 3 9 ;) but insert side the database get it as ' and it break the insert.

```
    Input $field1 = "toespits om &#39;n doelwit te bereik";

$query = "SELECT * FROM `action_templates` WHERE `templateid` = '$templateid' ";
$result=mysqli_query($DB1, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row == true) {
$field1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($DB1, $row['field1']); // or whatever escaping
...
...
}

$query="INSERT INTO `action_templates` ('NULL', `field1` '...', '...')";
mysqli_query($DB2, $query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
}  

Output $field1 = "toespits om 'n doelwit te bereik"; // &#39; seems to be inserted as '
```

Both database charsets are set as UTF8

Comment: you can use `db1`.`action_templates` and `db2`.`action_templates` to refer

Comment: Does your database user have select rights for the source database and insert rights for the destination database?

Comment: I not yet tried db1.table yet thank you (all db rights is in place yes)

Comment: I think that is the problem with "learn yourself" where you can learn all you need to know and eventually even do very complex things but there will perhaps always bo some basic things you never learnt.

Comment: After stuggled a lot I finally found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278304/5364868